# Is there any native way to obtain data from a combobox datasource

Tags: c#, mysql

I fill a combobox with some data from a database with 3 values: id as value member, name as displaymember, and email. I want to know if there is any way to access the object datasource and retrieve the value email.

I fill the combobox with data from a `MySQL` database and I tried searching some methods on `C#`, but none of them have succeeded.

I use this to fill the datasource:

```cs
foreach (Usuario item in usuarioDataModel)
{
    listUsuario.Add(new UsuarioModel
        {
            id_usuario = item.id_usuario,
            nombre = item.nombre,
            email = item.email                    
        }
    );
}
```

Then on presentation layer:

```cs
cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.DataSource = user.GetAllByDep(dep)
cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.ValueMember = "id_usuario"
cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.DisplayMember = "nombre"
```

I want to access email on combobox datasource this way:

```cs
string h = cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.DataSource.GetType()
```

I want to access email and then store it on string variable `h`.

Comment: `string h = ((UsuarioModel)cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.SelectedItem).email;` basically you need to cast out the item type and then you can get it's props/fields.

Comment: `string h = cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.DataSource.GetType()` will never work either, `string != type`. Also your datasource is a type of list, so `string h = cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.DataSource();` wouldn't even work. You would have to cast out the `DataSource`, for example `var lstItems = ((List<UsuarioModel>)cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.DataSource());` Now you have `lstItems` of all your items, but to get an email you would have to select one of them from this list: `var email = lstItems[0].email;`

Comment: or 
```UsuarioModel temp = new UsuarioModel();
temp = (UsuarioModel)cbxEditarTramiteFuncionario.SelectedItem();
string h = temp.email;
```
One way or another, you need a ```comboboxName.SelectedItem``` casted on a type of class that your combobox is storing

Comment: @MateuszBoruch reiterating my comment/s, thanks :)

Comment: It worked :)  Thank you for your help. I guess my aproach was bad from the start.

Comment: @Kanut777 you're welcome. You don't know unless you ask, right?